# getting additional PaperSource details

Tags: c#, .net, system.drawing

I'm trying to get the correct details of trays of various printers however have come across a problem. After a bit of research I've added the ReachFramework.dll and also

```
using System.Drawing.Printing;
```

To get the names of the trays for a printer I run the following code...

```
PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "<Windows Printer Name>";

foreach (PaperSource paperSource in printDocument.PrinterSettings.PaperSources)
{
    Console.WriteLine(paperSource.ToString());
}
```

...replacing 'Windows Printer Name'. For some printers it works great and I get something like the following output...

```
[PaperSource Auto Tray Select Kind=AutomaticFeed]
[PaperSource Tray 1 Kind=Upper]
[PaperSource Tray 2 Kind=Middle]
[PaperSource Tray 3 Kind=Lower]
[PaperSource Bypass Tray Kind=Manual]
```

Which is what you would expect. However for some printers I get the following...

```
[PaperSource  Automatically Select Kind=FormSource]
[PaperSource  Printer auto select Kind=Custom]
[PaperSource  Manual Feed in Tray 1 Kind=Custom]
[PaperSource  Tray 1 Kind=Custom]
[PaperSource  Tray 2 Kind=Custom]
[PaperSource  Tray 3 Kind=Custom]
[PaperSource Unspecified Kind=Custom]
[PaperSource Plain Kind=Custom]
[PaperSource HP Matte 90g Kind=Custom]
[PaperSource Light 60-74g Kind=Custom]
[PaperSource Bond Kind=Custom]
[PaperSource Recycled Kind=Custom]
[PaperSource HP Matte 105g Kind=Custom]
[PaperSource HP Matte 120g Kind=Custom]
[PaperSource HP Soft Gloss 120g Kind=Custom]
[PaperSource HP Glossy 130g Kind=Custom]
... Additional 20 lines ...
```

This printer returned 36 trays but only the first 6 are valid tray types. Additionally the printer is only equipped with 2 standard trays, so 'Tray 3' is doesn't exist either.

So my question is this. How can I filter this list so only the correct trays are showing?

Comment: were they all valid printers?  How were you iterating printers?

Comment: There was no need to iterate through printers in this example as all you need to do is fully name it, however I used System.Printing.LocalPrintServer().GetPrintQueues(enumFlags) to get the windows printer names.

Answer (score 3):

Found a partial answer by changing the foreach and adding an if statement like the following...

```
foreach (PaperSource paperSource in printDocument.PrinterSettings.PaperSources)
{
    if (paperSource.RawKind < 1000)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(paperSource.ToString());
    }
}
```

This produces the following output...

```
[PaperSource  Automatically Select Kind=FormSource]
[PaperSource  Printer auto select Kind=Custom]
[PaperSource  Manual Feed in Tray 1 Kind=Custom]
[PaperSource  Tray 1 Kind=Custom]
[PaperSource  Tray 2 Kind=Custom]
[PaperSource  Tray 3 Kind=Custom]
```

While not ideal it does solve the part of the problem. It doesn't however solve the issue of valid trays that do not exist.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of late  but I just wanted to add that I was doing very similar thing in VB.net and part about RawKind really helped cut through the "clutter". The way I'm going about it is bit different, I essentially want end user to capture printer and tray for  specific type of paper/printing. Then I can just print out reports without any prompts.

On my frmPrinterSelection i have two comboboxes; cboInstalledPrinters (to list installed printers), and cboPaperSource (to list paper source), below is my code. Hopefully it can help someone trying to capture printer and tray for later use.

```
    Private Sub frmPrinterSelection_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    cboInstalledPrinters.Items.Clear()
    Dim pkInstalledPrinters As String

    ' Find all printers installed
    For Each pkInstalledPrinters In
    PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters
        cboInstalledPrinters.Items.Add(pkInstalledPrinters)
    Next pkInstalledPrinters

    'https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings(v=vs.110).aspx
End Sub

Private Sub cboInstalledPrinters_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboInstalledPrinters.SelectionChangeCommitted

    Dim pkSource As Printing.PaperSource
    Dim strPrinter As String
    Dim printDoc As New Printing.PrintDocument
    Dim intTray As Integer
    cboPaperSource.Items.Clear()
    ' Add list of paper sources found on the printer to the combo box.
    ' The DisplayMember property is used to identify the property that will provide the display string.
    strPrinter = cboInstalledPrinters.SelectedItem
    printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = strPrinter
    For intTray = 0 To printDoc.PrinterSettings.PaperSources.Count - 1
        pkSource = printDoc.PrinterSettings.PaperSources.Item(intTray)
        If pkSource.RawKind < 1000 Then
            cboPaperSource.Items.Add(Trim(pkSource.SourceName))
        Else
            MsgBox(pkSource)
        End If
    Next
    Me.cboPaperSource.Focus()
    Me.cboPaperSource.DroppedDown = vbTrue
End Sub
```